# fish equivalent of ${this:-that} expansion and similar

Tags: fish

Trying `fish`, I am stuck on equivalents for some of the variable expansions from `bash`:

```
x=${this:-$that}
x=${this:-that}
```

How do I do that in fish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing so short as that posix shell variable expansion:

```
if set -q this; or test -z $this
    set x $that
else
    set x $this
end
```

or the "terse" version

```
begin; set -q this; or test -z $this; end; and set x $that; or set x $this
```

(I'll be happy to be proven wrong about this one)

Comment: Sorry you've answered a slightly more complicated question than I intended to ask :-) I intended the question as two separate examples, I should have split it into 2 code sections.

Comment: I don't think I did. This is what the sh `${var:-default}` expansion does: if the variable var is unset or empty, return the default value, else return the variable's value. This only difference in your two examples is `set x $that` versus `set x "that"`

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. So now I probably want to understand why you prefer `set -q this; or test -z $this` over `test -z "$this"` which would also deal with the two cases?

Comment: I was just being super explicit about the exact translation. Because in bash you can say `${this-$that}` that only returns the default value if the variable is unset -- if $this is set but empty, that's what you get